# Checkbox conditional validation in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I'm trying to make a form that validates **1 dropdown only if a checkbox is unchecked**. I ended up with the following code:

**HTML**

```
<label for="chk">Checkbox</label>
    <input type="checkbox"  class="chk" ID="chkID" name="mychkBox" checked="checked" value="true"/>

<select ID="dropdownID" name="myDropdown" title="please select something">
    <option value="0">-Select-</option>
        <option value="1">-Option1-</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#my-form").validate({
        rules: {
            myDropdown: {
                  required: "#chkID:unchecked",
                                  min:1
            }

        }//rules

});// end
$("#chkID").click(function() {          
      $("#dropdownID").valid();
      alert('gothere');
});
```

problem is it doesn't work, the form still submits. 
anyone know what I am missing/doing wrong?

-edit-
Do I need to check for anything if the dropdown is being populated by JSON? will this work the dame way?. Reason I ask is that the form works as intended before any errors in validation but afterwards it requires the dropdown even if the checkbox is checked or unchecked. This is exactly what I am trying to do though...

-edit-
Nevermind, I just hid/disabled the offending dropdown when the checkbox is checked so it will not validate

but I marked the answer "answered" since I forgot to mention about dynamically loaded content/HTML.

Comment: i couldn't see your form. but check box click function you are doing $("#dropdownID").valid(); which is wrong use form id instead of selector id. checkbox validation here---http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297555/jquery-validate-form-input-if-certain-check-boxes-are-checked

Comment: validation runs fine if I remove: "details: {required: "#chkID:unchecked"}" Tried using the form ID instead of the dropdown's the form still submits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HTML markup your select element is named `myDropdown`, and in your jQuery code you refer to it as `details`. Try changing your validation config to:

```
rules: { myDropdown: { required: "#chkID:unchecked" } }
```

*Edit*

Also, your default option in the select element should have an empty value. Otherwise the `required` rule will always be satisfied:

```
<option value="">-Select-</option>
```

I created a jsFiddle that should accomplish what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/BGWbu/

Comment: It now validates but does not care if the checkbox is unchecked or not. see my edit to view the changes I made

Comment: The problem is that your default option in the select element has a non-empty value. I updated my answer with more details.

Comment: Do I need to check for anything if the dropdown is being populet by JSON? will this work the dame way?

Comment: Should work the same way. The validator won't care how or when during the page lifecycle the dropdown is populated, just what values its option elements have in the DOM at the moment you are calling `.valid()` or submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a 'unchecked' selector, :S

try

```
"#chkID:not(:checked)"
```

also may be you need an if block, valid() returns boolean

```
if($("#dropdownID").valid()){
    alert('goThere');
}
```

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/unchecked <--I just got it from this example. changed it and still isn't working. =(